# C - division doesnt work

Tags: c, math, division

I'm actually totally stuck I don't understand the behavior of this function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct s_resolution
{
   int x;
   int y; 
   float fx;
   float fy;
} t_resolution;

typedef struct s_pixel_info
{
    int tablen;
    t_resolution resolution;
    char name;
    int line;
    int pos_suite[6];
    int suite[6];
} t_pixel_info;

void get_proportion_ratio(t_pixel_info DataB, t_pixel_info pix_info,
                           t_resolution *proportion)
{
    proportion->fx = (float)(DataB.resolution.x / pix_info.resolution.x);
    //I also tried without the cast
    proportion->y = (int)(DataB.resolution.y / pix_info.resolution.y * 100);
    //if (proportion->y != 100)
    printf("%d | %d | %d\n",proportion->y, DataB.resolution.y, pix_info.resolution.y);
}

int main()
{
  t_pixel_info DataB;
  t_pixel_info pix_info;
  t_resolution proportion;

  DataB.resolution.x = 5;
  pix_info.resolution.x = 10;
  DataB.resolution.y = 5;
  pix_info.resolution.y = 10;
  get_proportion_ratio(DataB, pix_info, &proportion);

}
```

`DataB.resolution.y`, `pix_info.resolution.y` and `proportion->y` are all `Int` type.
My problem is that I have this result:

```
0 | 5 | 10
```

The operation only works when the result is 100... I must be missing something obvious but I've no idea what.

Comment: Are you stuck with integer division issues?

Comment: Try this `proportion->fx = (DataB.resolution.x / (float)pix_info.resolution.x);`

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. And show clearly what you expect and what you get instead

Comment: Try this: `(float)(DataB.resolution.x / pix_info.resolution.x);` -> `((float)DataB.resolution.x / pix_info.resolution.x);`

Comment: And also `(int)(DataB.resolution.y / pix_info.resolution.y * 100);` -> `((100 * DataB.resolution.y) / pix_info.resolution.y);`

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your divisions are being done on integers.  Take this expression:

```
5 / 10 * 100
```

This groups as:

```
(5 / 10) * 100
```

This evaluates to `0`:  `5 / 10` is `0`, and `0 * 100` is still `0`.  Casting the result after the fact doesn't change it.

If you multiply by `100` *before* you divide, you will obtain two more digits of precision:

```
100 * 5 / 10
```

This evaluates to `50`:  `100 * 5` is `500`, and `500 / 10` is `50`.

You could also perform the arithmetic in floating point, e.g.

```
(double) 5 / (double) 10 * (double) 100
```

Or you could just cast the first operand and let the standard arithmetic conversions handle the rest; the result is equivalent:

```
(double) 5 / 10 * 100
```

In either case, the result will be `50.0`

Comment: Oh ok It all makes sense now. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since `resolution.x` and `resolution.y` are `int`s, the division between them will done as [`integer division`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers), which keeps only the "whole" part of the division. If you want to perform a floating point ("regular") division, you should cast to a floating point type **before** performing the division. E.g.:

```
proportion->fx = ((float) DataB.resolution.x) / ((float) pix_info.resolution.x);
```